# Git installation causing issues with nodemon...localhost not starting

Tags: node.js, git, localhost, nodemon

I recent installed git using Homebrew on my mac.   The install went ok.  Went I went back to my text editor and tried to run `npm` start, localhost would not start automatically.  When I type localhost:5000 manually (in my case),  I just get the error from this line of code (app.js file).  I have `nodemon` installed as a `devDependency`.  Prior to the git install, everything was working fine.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new HttpError('Could not find this route.', 404);
  throw error;
});
```

when I run npm start, these are the lines that are displayed...definitely different response than when git wasn't installed...

```
[nodemon] 2.0.6
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
```

Since the server does seem to start with out errors, I wondering if the git install could effect how `nodemon` functions?  Any guidance would be great